# Apache won't run after upgrading php version from 7.3.27 to 8.0.9, windows 10

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i was trying to upgrade my php from 7.3.27 to the latest, and i did it by following tutorial on https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-upgrade-lower-version-to-latest-php-version-in-xampp-on-windows-f7be9a70bbb0 but after i did it, apache won't start, it just say "Attempting to start Apache service" and that's it. the new php module setup on httpd-xampp.conf look like this :

```
#LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
LoadFile “C:/xampp/php/php8ts.dll”
LoadModule php8_module “C:/xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll”
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
```

Comment: Try using normal double quotes instead of those windows 'curly-looking' double quotes, which are not the same character. See the difference of the quotes on the last line and the commented-out line vs the other two.

Comment: i think you're right, but i already reinstall newer version of xampp